# BizTalk schemas not in referenced assembly

Tags: schema, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to reference schemas which are part of a BizTalk project in another BizTalk project which is not part of the same solution. I am referencing the source project by adding the source dll as a reference in my 'destination' project (i.e. 'Add Reference', 'Browse' point to the required biztalk schema assembly). However, when I look in the referenced assembly in object browser only a small subset of the schemas are available - none of the WCF generated schemas which form part of that project are visible.

Comparing the schema properties in the source project between the ones visible via object browser and those missing, they are all identical (other than File Name and Type Name) in that they all have the same Build Action (BtsCompile), all set as PropertySchema and all belong to the same namespace.

Does anyone have any suggestions around this please?

Comment: Are you sure the WCF generated schemas were generated in the schema project of your referenced solution

Comment: Hi @RedEyedMonster - yes, the schemas are definitely in the project/assembly of the referenced assembly. When I deploy that solution to biztalk, the schemas are present and listed as being in that assembly.

Comment: Did you build the source dll?  Do you have access to the original code so that you can rebuild?

Comment: Do you remember what worked for you? Can you please share?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this behaviour before when I had an older version of the assembly in the GAC, and Visual Studio was referencing that version rather than the version on disk. To check that this isn't the case, review your GAC and remove any references to your faulty schema, then restart Visual Studio before re-trying the re-compilation.

I would also be tempted to check that you are referencing the correct *version* of the assembly.

Alternatively, can you check whether it is just the WCF Schema's project that is broken? Create a new project with an entirely new assembly name and namespace and copy one of the faulty schemas across. Re-compile and reference in your project - can you see all of the expected properties of the previously faulty schema?

I would also try applying CU6 for BizTalk Server 2010 to see whether this addresses any issues you may have in your environment - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2855367

Comment: Another option to try would be to regenerate the WCF Schemas in a new project.